# How to dynamic cast an object from a parameter input

Tags: casting

I've a class Employee here

```
public class Employee 
{
    property1;
    property2;
    property3;
    property4;
}
```

and class EmployeeEntity

```
public class EmployeeEntity
{
    property1;
    property2;
    property5;
    property6;
}
```

2 these class don't inherit from another one class

I have the service like this

```
EmployeeService
public Employee getEmployee(Long employeeId)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    EmployeeInDatabase employeeInDatabase = employeeDao.findEmployeeById(employeeId);
    employee.setProperty1(employeeInDatabase .getProperty1());
    employee.setProperty2(employeeInDatabase .getProperty2());
    employee.setProperty3(employeeInDatabase .getProperty3());
    employee.setProperty4(employeeInDatabase .getProperty4());
    return employee;
}

public EmployeeEntity getEmployee(Long employeeId)
{
    EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = new EmployeeEntity();
    EmployeeInDatabase employeeInDatabase = employeeDao.findEmployeeById(employeeId);
    employeeEntity .setProperty1(employeeInDatabase .getProperty1());
    employeeEntity .setProperty2(employeeInDatabase .getProperty2());
    employeeEntity .setProperty5(employeeInDatabase .getProperty5());
    employeeEntity .setProperty6(employeeInDatabase .getProperty6());
    return employeeEntity;
}
```

As you see that I have many dupplicated implementation for setProperty1(), setProperty2()

How could I try by this way?

EmployeeConverter

```
public Object setProperty1AndProperty2(Object employee, EmployeeInDatabase employeeInDatabase)
{
    Object response;
    if(employee instanceof Employee)
    {
        response = (Employee) employee;
    }
    if(employee instanceof EmployeeInDatabase)
    {
        response = (EmployeeInDatabase) employee;
    }
    response.setPropery1(employee.getProperty1());
    response.setPropery2(employee.getProperty2());
}
```

From there we could use setProperty1AndProperty2 with 2 object Employee, EmployeeEntity.

Is there anyone have some solution? Thanks  :)

Comment: What programming language is this, C# or C++?

Comment: You can use generic classes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: If this is C#, you could use [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to populate the members of an object.

Comment: Sorry Codor, its in Java... :)

Comment: @PriyanshGoel : is there any different way? Because I coulnd not use the generic or extend from a common class for this case.